# Enable php5-curl on OpenSuse with Nginx

Tags: php, nginx

I have OpenSuse Server 10.3 with nginx for web server.

I need to enable php5-curl. Installed it successfully. Then restarted web server, but nothing changed.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You probably didn't actually load the extension yet. Look at your phpinfo() to find out where PHP is looking for .ini files. If you have a section labelled something like "Scan this dir for additional .ini files", then make a new file in that directory ('curl.ini') with the single line:

```
extension=curl.so
```

If you don't have a 'Scan' dir, look for 'Loaded Configuration File' and append the same line to the end of that file.

Comment: keep in mind (i didnt realise this with much frustration) that to make changes in a php.ini to take effect, you have to restart your php child launcher, not nginx, (as you do with apache) for me it was  /etc/init.d/php-fcgi-your-domain restart