# PHP :Why PHP-Curl is not working with nginx

Tags: php, curl, nginx

I recently moved my website to a nginx server. My python code is running on the same machine on 8086 port, but my php curl module is not working. I don't know what I am doing wrong here.

I already installed `php5-fpm`, but stil not able to resolve this issue. I can not see the error also because nginx simply shows me the blank screen. Btw. it is printing all the values before `curl_init()` statement.

I can post my Nginx configuration also but i don't think so that is required.

Comment: Well, do you have the curl module installed in PHP? http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.installation.php

Comment: php5-curl is already the newest version.

Comment: What is `phpinfo()` telling you? Are you seeing curl support there?

Comment: let me check i didn't try

Comment: I don't see curl support here. My guess would be you have multiple PHP binaries on your machine and you've installed curl in the wrong one

Comment: ok one more thing does my php version support curl or not

Comment: I don't know - curl support doesn't seem to be compiled into it, though. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.installation.php

Comment: I'm guessing you'd have to recompile the PHP binary that you are using for nginx. I don't know how to do that though, sorry

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25210/discussion-between-masterofdestiny-and-pekka-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135860/enable-php5-curl-on-opensuse-with-nginx

Answer (score 16):

You need to run `/etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart`

Comment: @masterofdestiny you should mark this as the answer.

Comment: This was indeed the solution for me. Allthough  I had some problems with php5-fpm not restarting upon writing that command. I had to manually kill all instances of php5-fpm and then start it anew. And then - worked fine!

Comment: My php curl stopped working randomly, but curl was still working on the server. Restarting php5.6-fpm fixed the issue for us...thanks!

Comment: Thx. It was `systemctl restart php-fpm` for me. No idea why that needed a restart.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, make sure to follow the below steps:

1. Rename `php.ini-production` or `php.ini-development` to `php.ini`
2. Specify the extension directory: `extension_dir = "ext"`
3. Enable the Curl extension (Uncomment in php.ini): `extension=php_curl.dll`